# Is it possible to use HealthKit in Swift Playgrounds on iPad?

Tags: swift, ipad, healthkit

I'm trying to connect my Swift Playgrounds app which is being developed on iPad to Apple Watch. Importing HealthKit in swift file and accessing its classes and methods works perfectly, but in a runtime I get an error saying that NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription key should be set in info.plist file. The problem is that iPad Swift Playgrounds app does not have any info.plist file and as far as I know this file is autogenerated.

So my question is - is it possible at all to use HealthKit in Swift Playgrounds app which is being developer on iPad? If yes - how can I set up NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription?

Comment: Check out this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/setting_up_healthkit

Comment: This only describes the basic info regarding HealthKit and its setup with XCode, but I'm using Swift Playgrounds on the iPad.

Comment: No, there is no HealthKit on iPad.

Comment: It is possible to add arbitrary Info.plist keys to a Swift Playgrounds app, see the following blog post. *However*, I don't know much about HealthKit, but I wouldn't be surprised if it requires an *entitlement* in addition to Info.plist keys, and you cannot add arbitrary entitlements to a Swift Playgrounds app. You can only add a small subset of entitlements exposed as "capabilities" in the project editor, and I don't see HealthKit among them as of 2022. Maybe in the future. https://www.rambo.codes/posts/2021-12-28-a-document-based-app-in-swift-playgrounds-for-ipad

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of Swift Playgrounds as of March 6, 2023, it doesn’t look like you can add the HealthKit capability. Since this is required in order to use HealthKit, it seems like there is currently no way to use HealthKit in Swift Playgrounds on iPad.